# Multi-Currency & Website Setup

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

I have a scenario whereby I need the following currency requirements out of my Magento 1 website.

1. Three currencies GBP, USD, EUR
2. GBP is base currency for UK orders
3. USD is base currency for US orders
4. EUR is base currency for European orders

I have identified that I need to have 3 different website views to achieve this.

The complication is that the USD price has to be a direct conversion of the GBP price but **without** tax. The EUR price has to be a direct conversion of the GBP price but **with** tax. The base currency must also be maintained for each country as specified above.

Does anybody know of a way of doing this by default in Magento or would I need an extension/custom solution.